# Django / User access in ManyToMany field

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am making a django app using the `User` class from `django.contrib.auth.models`.

I have defined a model, called a *group* with a M2M relationship to users.  I have difficulty retrieving the groups a given user belongs to.

Here's the *group* definition:

```
class group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'owner') # the owner
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # name of the group 

    # members of the group
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name = 'member')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

I would like to retrieve the groups for which the user belongs to the *members* field of the groups.

Here is the command that fails, trying to retrieve the groups that a particular user belongs to - I am not sure why - could you let me know ?  (`user` is a `User` instance)

```
user_groups = user.group_set.all()
```

The error I get is:

```
 'User' object has no attribute 'group_set'
```

What's wrong here?

**SOLUTION**

I eventually found the solution. I had to make the query with the `related_name`, so here it is:

```
groups_member = user.member.all()
```

Answer (score 11):

Because the many-to-many relation is through the `members` property, and this property has the `related_name` attribute, the correct syntax is:

```
user_groups = user.member.all()
```

( Without the related name attribute, it would be `user_groups = user.members_set.all()` )

And the reverse relation is:

```
group_users = group.members.all()
```

Comment: Ok, remember to check answer as solution.